# How to associate two models with sequelize? (1:n) and (m:n)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to make 3 tables `Cliente`, `Obra` and `Engenheiro`.

Associations: `Cliente` relates to `Obra` (1:n) and `Engenheiro` relates to `Obra` (m:n).

**Cliente.js:**

```
const db = require('./db');
const Obra = require('./Obra');

const Cliente = db.sequelize.define('clientes', {
    nome: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    celular: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    cpf: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

Cliente.hasMany(Obra);

//Cliente.sync({force: true})

module.exports = Cliente
```

**Engenheiro.js:**

```
const db = require('./db');
const Registro = require('./Registro');

const Engenheiro = db.sequelize.define('engenheiros', {
    nome: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    }
    crea: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    salario: {
        type: db.Sequelize.FLOAT
    }
});

Engenheiro.hasMany(Obra);

//Engenheiro.sync({force: true})

module.exports = Engenheiro
```

**Obra.js:**

```
const db = require('./db')
const Cliente = require('./Cliente');
const Registro = require('./Registro');

const Obra = db.sequelize.define('obras', {
    bairro: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    cidade: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    estado: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

Obra.belongsTo(Cliente);
Obra.hasMany(Engenheiro);

//Obra.sync({force: true})

module.exports = Obra
```

Error message when i call "node something.js":
"something.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model"

**Update:**
I tried what Anatoly said and it executed without any error, but I don't see a new column appearing and the sql code of the association didn't appear on the console, am i doing something wrong?
I create a new model "Registro.js" and moved the ".sync()" and the associations to a new file:

**Association.js**

```
const Cliente = require('./Cliente');
const Engenheiro = require('./Engenheiro');
const Obra = require('./Obra');
const Registro = require('./Registro');

Cliente.sync({force: true});
Engenheiro.sync({force: true});
Obra.sync({force: true});
Registro.sync({force: true});

Cliente.hasMany(Obra);
Obra.belongsTo(Cliente);
Obra.belongsToMany(Engenheiro, { through: Registro });
Engenheiro.belongsToMany(Obra, { through: Registro });
```

**Registro.js(All models follow the same structure):**

```
const db = require('./db');

const Registro = db.sequelize.define('registros', {});

module.exports = Registro
```

Console (the tables looks bigger because I added new columns):

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `clientes`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `engenheiros`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `obras`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `registros`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `nome` VARCHAR(255), `end` VARCHAR(255), `fone` VARCHAR(255), `celular` VARCHAR(255), `cpf` VARCHAR(255), `cnpj` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `obras` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `end` VARCHAR(255), `bairro` VARCHAR(255), `cidade` VARCHAR(255), `estado` VARCHAR(255), `metragem` VARCHAR(255), `quartos` VARCHAR(255), `wc` VARCHAR(255), `infraestrutura` TINYINT(1), `garagem` TINYINT(1), `andar` VARCHAR(255), `edificio` VARCHAR(255), `situacao` VARCHAR(255), `dataInicio` DATETIME, `dataTermino` DATETIME, `observacao` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `engenheiros` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `nome` VARCHAR(255), `end` VARCHAR(255), `fone` VARCHAR(255), `celular` VARCHAR(255), `cpf` VARCHAR(255), `crea` VARCHAR(255), `salario` FLOAT, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registros` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `clientes`
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `obras`
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `engenheiros`
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `registros`
```

**Update2:**
I managed to create the relationship columns by placing the associations before `.sync()` and changing `force` to `alter` but I still don't understand how associations work.
In the example below when I change the order of the `.sync(alter: true)` some table are not created neither updated, and the associations fail.

```
const Cliente = require('./Cliente');
const Obra = require('./Obra');
const Engenheiro = require('./Engenheiro');
const Registro = require('./Registro');

Cliente.hasMany(Obra);
Obra.belongsTo(Cliente);
Obra.belongsToMany(Engenheiro, {through: Registro});
Engenheiro.belongsToMany(Obra, {through: Registro});

Obra.sync({alter: true});
Engenheiro.sync({alter: true});
Cliente.sync({alter: true});
Registro.sync({alter: true});
```

Why the `sync(force:true)` causes the code to fail and why the order of the `sync` matter?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do is move all association definitions outside of model files OR add them to `associate` method of models to call them all later after all models will be already registered, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) for example.

Second, if you need M:N association you should create an additional table and define a model (let's say its name would be `EngenheiroObra` for instance) to link `Engenheiro` to `Obra` using `belongsToMany` method of a model.

```js
Engenheiro.belongsToMany(Obra, { though: EngenheiroObra });
Obra.belongsToMany(Engenheiro, { though: EngenheiroObra });
```

**Upd.** You also need to remove all association definitions from model files if you already moved them outside. And you don't need old `hasMany` associations because you replaced them with `belongsToMany` ones.

Comment: Please add `Registro` model definition.

Comment: Also you should register all association BEFORE calling `sync` methods

Comment: In the sequelize's documentation says that i need to put the `hasMany` together with `belongsTo` to make one-to-many association.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#one-to-many-relationships

Comment: For `Cliente` and `Obra` definitely, because you wish to link them as 1:n. But for `Engenheiro` and `Obra` you wish `m:n` that's why you need an additional table and model and use `belongsToMany` from both models to each other.