# Sequelize model.create is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize and trying to set it up for my new project. I checked some answers on this, but couldnt get past my error. Can someone point out how to fix this.

models/index.js

```
// Database service
// Connects to the database
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const path = require('path');


const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: process.env.QUERY_LOGGING == "true" ? console.log : false,
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
      }
});


module.exports = sequelize
```

models/users.js

```
const sequelize = require("./index")
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('Users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
          },
        firstName: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING,
              allowNull: false
         },
        lastName: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        profileURL: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        emailId: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING,
             allowNull: false 
        },
        passwordHash: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        street: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        city: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING,
             allowNull: false 
        },
        phone: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING 
        },
        newsletter: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING
         },
        visibility: {
             type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
             defaultValue: true
        },

    },{
    });
    return User;
};
```

And finally, I'm importing the User model in my service file like below:

```
const User = require("../models/users")

const createUser = async(req) => {
    const {firstName, lastName, profileURL, emailId, passwordHash, street, city, phone, newsletter, visibility} = req.body
    const user = await User.create({
        firstName, 
        lastName,
        profileURL, 
        emailId,
        passwordHash,
        street,
        city,
        phone,
        newsletter,
        visibility     
    })
    console.log("new user==>>", user)
    return
}

module.exports = { createUser }
```

However, I get the following error.

`TypeError: User.create is not a function`

Can someone point out what I could be doing wrong? I realize it could be something minor.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You export a function that registers the `User` model and not the model itself. So you just need to call it passing `sequelize` instance and `DataTypes` somewhere like `database.js` where you will register all models and their associations or directly in `models/index.js`:

```js
const UserModelConstructor = require("../models/users")
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
...
const UserModel = UserModelConstructor(sequelize, DataTypes);

module.exports = {
  sequelize,
  User: UserModel
}
```

You can look at how to register multiple models and association in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)

Please don't forget to remove this line

```
const sequelize = require("./index")
```

from `models/users.js`

Comment: Thank you very much. I referred your older answer and it worked