# Sequelize foreing key is not creating

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I try to create a relation between 2 tables with Sequelize in NodeJS for MariaDB.

I have 2 tables **order** and **local**, the table order needs **one of** the information of the table local.

The **order** table contains information about an order (id: 1, type: Jacket, color: blue, tracking_number: TR123)

The **table** local contains information about the place where the order is stored (address: 20 rue madeline, city: Paris)

I tried to link the two tables but it does not work, the foreing key is not created

**models/order.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Order = sequelize.define('order', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        trackingNumber: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        color: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        tel: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        createdAt: true,
        updatedAt: 'updateTimestamp'
    })

    Order.associate = function (models) {
        Order.hasOne(models.local);
    }

    return Order;
}
```

**models/local.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Local = sequelize.define('local', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        adress: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        informations_about: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        contact: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        city: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        zip: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(5),
            allowNull: false
        },

    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        createdAt: true,
        updatedAt: 'updateTimestamp'
    })
    return Local;
}
```

**app.js**

```
// Imports
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const db = require('./database')
const sequelize = require('./database').sequelize;

var apiRouter = require('./apiRouter.js').router;
var helmet = require('helmet');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Init server
app.use(morgan('combined'))

// Parser config
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// Security API
app.use(helmet());
app.disable('x-powered-by');


app.use(({ res }) => {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "404 Not Found" })
})

db.sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(_ => console.log("La connexion à bien été établie."))
    .catch(error => console.log(`error ${error}`))

db.sequelize.sync({ force: true })
    .then(_ => {
        console.log("Base de donnée synchronisée.")
        app.use('/api/', apiRouter);
    })


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is up and listening in " + port)
})
```

**database.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const db = {}
const models = path.join(__dirname, 'models') // correct it to path where your model files are

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    '',
    '',
    '',
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mariadb',
        dialectOptions: {
            useUTC: false, // for reading from database
        },
        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        },
        logging: false
    }
)

var basename = path.basename(module.filename)

fs
    .readdirSync(models)
    .filter(function (file) {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
    })
    .forEach(function (file) {
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname + '/models', file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
        db[model.name] = model
    })

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db)
    }
})

db.Sequelize = Sequelize // for accessing static props and functions like Op.or
db.sequelize = sequelize // for accessing connection props and functions like 'query' or 'transaction'

module.exports = db
```

Despite the associate function in the **model/order.js** it does not work, I have no key in my **order** table

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually call all `associate` functions in order to register associations between models and only after all models are already registered in the Sequelize instance. You can look at my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to see how you can do it.
And please show the content of `database` module and then I probably correct my answer or append more useful tips.

Comment: I updated my code in the post with your answer but I still don't have a "localId" key in my orders table :/

Comment: Try to add an opposite association `Local.belongsTo(models.order)`

Comment: Still no result, I tried to move the association all over the code but I never get any association I start to get discouraged lol. My version of Sequelize is 6.8.0

Comment: Wait, wait, wait! If you wish that an order should have a link to a local then you need `Order.belongsTo(models.local)` and not `hasOne`. You should call `belongsTo` of a model that has a link field to a model that is indicated as the first argument in `belongsTo`.

Comment: Alright, i tried : ```Order.associate = function (models){Order.belongsTo(models.local)};``` but still nothing on the horizon, I also tried to opposite the association

Comment: And no luck again?

Comment: I'm about to curl up under my desk

Comment: The last thing I can propose is to indicate the field `localId` on `Order` model explicitly and don't forget to indicate `references` option in this field description.

Comment: Ok I'm going to do that now, it's just that when I retrieve the data with order.findAll how can I add the data from the local table to each order object with the associated local_id?

Comment: That's another question ). Please create a new one here and post a link to it here. In short you need to add `include` option