# How to add instance and class level methods to a Model when using sequelize.define

Tags: sequelize.js

I am working with Sequelize for the first time and am have structured my application in a similar way as shown in the [official Sequelize github](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example).

Each model is setup in its own file (e.g.):

[user.mode.js](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/express-main-example/sequelize/models/user.model.js)

```js
    const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
    
    // We export a function that defines the model.
    // This function will automatically receive as parameter the Sequelize connection object.
    module.exports = (sequelize) => {
        sequelize.define('user', {
            // The following specification of the 'id' attribute could be omitted
            // since it is the default.
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER
            },
            username: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: true,
                validate: {
                    // We require usernames to have length of at least 3, and
                    // only use letters, numbers and underscores.
                    is: /^\w{3,}$/
                }
            },
        });
    };
```

Each of the models is then pulled in to the application as so:

[index.js](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/express-main-example/sequelize/index.js)

```js
    const modelDefiners = [
        require('./models/user.model'),
        require('./models/instrument.model'),
        require('./models/orchestra.model'),
        // Add more models here...
        // require('./models/item'),
    ];
    
    // We define all models according to their files.
    for (const modelDefiner of modelDefiners) {
        modelDefiner(sequelize);
    }
```

I'd like to add specific functions to each of the models so that the functions are available elsewhere in my application, however I am not sure how best to do this. There is an [example](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#extending--a-href-----class-lib-model-js-model-html--model--a-) in the Sequelize documentation however that only shows hows to do it if extending the model class. I could try and refactor to match this, but wanted to see if there was a way to do it as per the example setup provided by Sequelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a return value of `sequelize.define` into a local variable and use it to define some static methods and even return this registered model to use it to call all model methods including your own ones.
See [my answer and the question itself here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, unique: true, primaryKey: true },
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'role_id' });
  };
  return User;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I am not sure I am following based on the link you shared.

Comment: Look at an example I added to my answer above

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Will have a play! Thanks for swift response.