# Sequelize: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I have `Orders` and `Display` models. The association works like this

```
Display.associate = models => Display.hasOne(models.Orders);
```

The `orders` table has `displayId` reference and there is nothing circular in my design. However I get this error below.

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property '_writableState' -> object with constructor 'WritableState'
    |     property 'afterWriteTickInfo' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'stream' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

the error dissapears if I do not include `dbDisplay` shown below.

```
export const getAllOrders = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("GET ALL ORDERS")
    let orders = await dbOrders.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: dbDisplay,
        }]
    }).catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    try {
        res.status(200).send(orders) // error here

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to send model instances themselves. Use their `get({ plain: true })` method to get plain object(s):

```js
export const getAllOrders = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("GET ALL ORDERS")
    try {
        const orders = await dbOrders.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: dbDisplay,
        }]
        })
        res.status(200).send(orders.map(x => x.get({ plain: true })))
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).send(err) 
    }
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: orders.map is not a function`

Comment: The result of `let orders = await dbOrders.findAll({` should be an array. Can you check that?

Comment: And please don't mix `then/catch` and `await`. Use try/catch` with `await` to catch errors and send them to a client

Comment: orders is a complex object that has some [Circular] value on some variables

Comment: try updated code in the answer

Comment: now I get that `[SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: display is not associated to orders!` even though I do that as shown above

Comment: You didn't register associations properly. Look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618 to figure out how to do it