# I created oneToMany relation but how I can get the single record belongs to the many record in Sequalize

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

**Tagcategories Model**

```
export const TagCategories = sequelize.define(
  "tag_categories",
  {
    categoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: "category_id",
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      field: "title",
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },

  },

);

TagCategories.hasMany(TagGroups, {
  foreignKey: "categoryId",
  sourceKey: "categoryId",
});
export default TagCategories;
```

**TagGroups Model**

```
export const TagGroups = sequelize.define(
  "tag_groups",
  {
    tagGroupId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: "tag_group_id",
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },

    categoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: "category_id",
      allowNull: false,
    },

    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      field: "title",
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
);
```

In the above models I establish oneToMany relationship between the TagCategories and TagGroups

But I want to fetch the record from the TagGroup table with the TagCategories details.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at examples in [official documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html)?
Also, you need to add an association from `TagGroups` to `TagCategories`:

```js
// there is no need to indicate `sourceKey` if this field is a primary key
TagGroups.belongsTo(TagCategories, {
  foreignKey: "categoryId",
});
```

It's better to define all associations in static functions and call all of them separately after all models will be registered.
See the question and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) how to do it

In your case, the final request would be something like this

```js
const tagGroup = await TagGroups.findOne({
  where: {
     tagGroupId: groupId
  },
  include: [{
     model: TagCategories
  }]
})
```