# Associations with Sequelize Node/Express.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I got some trouble understanding how associations works with Sequelize. I am working on a project which have almost the same features that Reddit and therefore I am trying to associate the User table to the Post table as a 1:N associations.

User Model:

```
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require ('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/db');
const Post = require('./Post')


class User extends Model{}

User.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    username:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    isAdmin:{
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
}, {sequelize: db, modelName:'User'}
);


User.hasMany(Post,{as: 'posts', foreignKey: 'id'});

User.sync();

module.exports = User;
```

Post Model:

```
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require ('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/db');
const User = require('./User');


class Post extends Model{}

Post.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    text:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    image:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    likes:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    }
}, {sequelize: db, modelName:'Post'}
)


Post.sync();

module.exports = Post;
```

When I launch my app, I can see that it mention that post have the foreign key id but still I don't have hany column that link User to Post in my DB. What I am missing?

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Posts` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `text` VARCHAR(255), `image` VARCHAR(255), `likes` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), **FOREIGN KEY (`id`)** REFERENCES `Users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You do? HasMany creates foreign key on target table(Post). `FOREIGN KEY (\`id\`) REFERENCES \`Users\` (\`id\`)`  is the command that creates it. Check your database. You can view table information with the command `DESCRIBE Posts`

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

I've checked my DB and and my Posts table don't have any column that links it with my User model. I think because it's refering to the same primary key `id` from post.
Do I have to create an `user_id` column in my Post model to associate this two models?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to indicate the correct value in the `foreignKey` option, it should be a field like `user_id` in Post model:

```js
User.hasMany(Post,{as: 'posts', foreignKey: 'user_id'});
```

Second, you need to move association definitons and `sync` calls (and cross-refrences of models) from model modules outside. You need to register all models and only after that to define all their associations and the last  action would be calling `sync` methods.
See the question and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to get an idea how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I can't upvote yet but you made my day