# Sequelize association not a subclass of Sequelize.model?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I am trying to creat an assistion between my tables like this:

```
Customers.associate = (models) => {
      Customers.hasMany(models.Addresses, {foreignKey: 'id', as: 'aId', 
        onDelete: "cascade",
      });
  
      Customers.hasMany(models.Orderline, {
        onDelete: "cascade",
      });
    };
```

I have a customers table where a customer can have many addresses if they wish and many orders. I keep getting this error:

throw new Error(`${this.name}.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`);
Error: Customers.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

I have looked online for suggestions but I´m still stuck. Thanks for any help/guidance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if you register all models **BEFORE** registering any associations. You can look how to do it in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)
Second you need to correct the first `hasMany` association definition because I highly doubt that Addresses has `id` column as a foreign key column pointing to Customers:

```js
// assuming Addresses has customerId as a foreign key column we need to indicate it:
Customers.hasMany(models.Addresses, {foreignKey: 'customerId', as: 'addresses', 
        onDelete: "cascade",
      });
```

Maybe it would be a good idea to indicate a foreign key in other `hasMany` association as well:

```js
Customers.hasMany(models.Orderline, {
        foreignKey: 'customerId',
        onDelete: "cascade",
      });
```