# How to do a query in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've an existing Postgres database. Throught sequelize-auto, I generated the models for the existing database. For example, let's look at the `tc_devices` table (`tc_devices.js`):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('tc_devices', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      autoIncrementIdentity: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: false
    },
    uniqueid: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: "tc_devices_uniqueid_key"
    },
    lastupdate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    positionid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    groupid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'tc_groups',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    attributes: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(4000),
      allowNull: true
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: true
    },
    model: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: true
    },
    contact: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(512),
      allowNull: true
    },
    category: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
      allowNull: true
    },
    disabled: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'tc_devices',
    schema: 'public',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "tc_devices_pkey",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "tc_devices_uniqueid_key",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "uniqueid" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

In `database.js`, I connect to the database:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
    host,
    port,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false
  })

async function db_connection(){  
try{
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been estabilished successfully.');
}catch{
  console.log('Unable to connect to the database.');
}
}

db_connection()
```

How can I do a simple query on the tc_devices table? what should I import in `database.js`? in `tc_devices` I export `function(sequelize, DataTypes)`... but I can't understand how to do a query in `database.js` with this function...could you help me? thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register all models and their associations before executing the first query with these models. Look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618).
As soon as you do it you can execute queries like this:

```js
// assuming db already stores all model definitions
const allRecords = await db.tcDevices.findAll({})
```