# When does a Sequelize (ORM) instance method need `sequelize.` to refer to a different model and when not?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Suppose inside a model you have the following Sequelize instance method:

```
const Admins = require("./admin");

Organization.prototype.getAdmins = function () {
    // option 1
    return Admins.findAll({ where: 
        { organization_id: this.getDataValue("id") }
    });

    // option 2
    return sequelize.Admins.findAll({ where: 
        { organization_id: this.getDataValue("id") }
    });
};
```

Sometimes I see it written as option 1 and sometimes as option 2. When do you need which option? That is, when do you need to prepend `sequelize.` before the model that you are referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you import in a certain model file: `sequelize` instance or an initialized model (that also should be initialized using `sequelize` instance).
The goal is to access needed model to call its methods like `findAll`.
It's up to you what approach to use but I'd recommend to access all models from `sequelize` instance or from your own object that will store all initialized models (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)).

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly, At the top of the model file, I have: `const sequelize = require("../db");`. This calls on a file that includes `const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');`  `const sequelize = new Sequelize();`.  Am I correct to conclude that with this setup I should use option 1?

Comment: It would be much better to return a function that register a model and pass `sequilize` to it. That way you avoid importing `sequelize` in model files.