# Sequelize: Different SQLite Database per User

Tags: typescript, sqlite, sequelize.js, sveltekit, sequelize-typescript

My web app is architected in such a way that each user has a separate SQLite database with their data in it. I'm trying to get Sequelize to work within that. I'm using SvelteKit which is essentially Node on the back-end.

A user's ID gets passed into a function and then their database is initialized and returned like this:

```js
//--- db.ts ---
export function db(user: string){

  const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: './db/'+user+'/Database.sqlite'
  })

  return sequelize
}

//--- stuff.ts ---
import { db } from 'db'

const stuff = db(userId)
```

This is all fine and good, but I don't know how to take advance of `Model` definitions because I have to be able to pass them the instance of `Sequelize` in order for it to be initialized:

```js
//--- field.ts ---
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize'

class Field extends Model {}

Field.init({
  name:{ type: DataTypes.STRING }
}, {
  sequelize, // <-- Need the instance
  modelName: 'Field' 
})
```

From what I can tell, I have to put my `Field` definition inside `db.ts` and initialize it every time I access the instance of `Sequelize`. But then won't `Field` only be available within the context of the `db` function?

Is this the proper way to use extreme sharding with Sequelize? Is there a way to define the `Field` class generally and then give it the `sequelize` instance later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap all model definition code into a function that has two parameters: `sequelize` and `DataTypes`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709290/sequelize-model-association-wont-create-a-new-column) and my answer there to get an idea how to register models and associations.