# ERROR:TypeError: user.getTempContributions is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize6.17, and lazy loading doesn't work.
I use function getTempContributions() that generate by the Sequelize, but it take a Error that user.getTempContributions is not a function.And I try for many ways.I add a function declare in the class UserCard, and It seems that sequelize doesn't generatef function getTempContributions() correctly. I don't know it's something wrong for me to take this code.

**Error**

```
TypeError: user.getTempContributions is not a function
    at F:\builderBackend\src\Temp\test.ts:7:48
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (F:\builderBackend\src\Temp\test.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I have try many ways, but it also doesn't work.And that's my last code.

**test.ts**

```
import {TempContribution, TempTask} from "./model";
import {UserCard} from "../Authority/model";

(async ()=>{
    const user:UserCard|null = await UserCard.findByPk(1);
    if(user){
        const tempTask:TempTask[] = await user.getTempContributions();
        console.log(tempTask);
    }
})()
```

**Authority/model**

```
import {sequelize} from "../../database";
import {Model, DataTypes, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes} from "sequelize";
import {TempTask} from "../Temp/model";

class UserCard extends Model {
    declare userId: number;
    declare address: string;
    declare email: string;
    declare google: string;
    declare avatar: string;
    declare getTempContributions: () => Promise<TempTask[]>;
}

UserCard.init({
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    address: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        validate: {isEmail: true}
    },
    google: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    avatar: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: "lena.jpg"
    },
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "UserCard",
});

export {UserCard};
```

**model.ts**

```
import {DataTypes, Model} from "sequelize";
import {sequelize} from "../../database";
import {UserCard} from "../Authority/model";

class TempTask extends Model{
    declare id: number;
}

class TempContribution extends Model{
    declare status: string;
}

TempTask.init({
    id:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true
    }
},{
    sequelize,
    timestamps:false,
    modelName:"TempTask"
});

TempContribution.init({
    status:DataTypes.ENUM("processing","submitted")
},{
    sequelize,
    modelName:"TempContribution",
    timestamps:false
});

//@ts-ignore
TempTask.hasMany(TempContribution);
//@ts-ignore
TempContribution.belongsTo(TempTask);
//@ts-ignore
UserCard.hasMany(TempContribution);
//@ts-ignore
TempContribution.belongsTo(UserCard);


export {TempTask,TempContribution};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please register all models using functions and only after that register all associations.
See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to get an idea how to do it.