# Typescript Sequelize Add Relantionship crashing the app

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Hello I started learning typescript, made one admin model, and role model, when I try to add belongs to to roleId I am getting error. Can someone pls check what can be the issue , I am not able to resolve it.

```
import { Admin } from '@interfaces/admin.interface';
import RoleModel from './role.model';

export type AdminCreationAttributes = Optional<Admin, 'id' | 'email'>;

export class AdminModel extends Model<Admin, AdminCreationAttributes> implements Admin {
  public id: number;
  public email: string;
  public role_id: number;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

export default function (sequelize: Sequelize): typeof AdminModel {
  AdminModel.init(
    {
      id: {
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      },
      role_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: 'Admins',
      sequelize,
    },
  );

  AdminModel.hasMany(RoleModel, {foreignKey: 'role_id', as: 'roles', targetKey: 'id'});
  return AdminModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't import `DataTypes` from `sequelize` package.
Second, you need to register all models and only after that register all associations. To get the idea how to do it see [my other answer to the similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)