# How to structure sequelize sync to able resolve by sequelize instance?

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to sync all table a.k.a create table if not exists. i follow this [official tutorial](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#synchronizing-all-models-at-once) rather than call sync one by one each model. theres single call can sync all. sequelize.sync() but it do nothing. i try to  try catch no error too. current sequelize version 6.25.2. setup.js to action to create table. its like sequelize instance doesn't resolve model.

sequelize-client.js

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(username, password, database);
export { sequelize }
```

models folder
user.js

```
import { sequelize } from "sequelize-client.js";
const User = sequelize.define("User",  {
    id: {
        type: BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
        type: STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

models folder account.js

```
const Account = sequelize.define("Account", {
    id: {
        type: BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    accoundId: {
        type: STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: DATE,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

setup.js

```
import { sequelize } from "sequelize-client.js";
sequelize.sync({ force: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create tables properly using `sync` method of Sequelize instance you need to register all models and their associations prior to calling `sync`. I recommend to look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to find out how to do it.