# Generated table using belongstomany is not associated with any table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three tables companies, subscriptions and companySubscription. As name defined company can canbuy/have plan or one subscription belongs to many companies.

So in model/schema I have defined as follows:

companies.js

```
const sequelize = require("../utils/database");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const subscription = require("./subscriptions");
const CompanySubscription = require("./companySubscription");

class companies extends Model {}

companies.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    contactNo: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    companySize: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: "companies" }
);

subscription.belongsToMany(companies, { through: CompanySubscription });

module.exports = companies;
```

subscription.js

```
const sequelize = require("../utils/database");

const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");

class subscription extends Model {}

subscription.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    subscriptionPlanType: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ["Yearly", "Monthly"],
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    memberCount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    amount: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: "subscription" }
);

module.exports = subscription;
```

companySubscription.js

```
const sequelize = require("../utils/database");
const companies = require("./companies");
const subscription = require("./subscriptions");
const { DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");

class CompanySubscription extends Model {}

CompanySubscription.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ["active", "inactive"],
    },
    subscriptionType: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ["Yearly", "Monthly"],
    },
    subscriptionPlanStartDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    subscriptionPlanEndDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    paidStatus: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ["paid", "unpaid"],
    },
    paidDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: "CompanySubscription" }
);

module.exports = CompanySubscription;
```

In controller file I am able to manage to insert the data. Below is the code:

```
const addBIlling = async (req, res) => {
  const foundSubcscription = await subscription.create({
    subscriptionPlanType: "Monthly",
    name: "s1",
    memberCount: 15,
    amount: 50.55,
  });

  const foundCompany = await companies.create({
    name: "company1",
    email: "company1@gmail.com",
    contactNo: "87964644",
    companySize: 20,
  });

  const insertedData = await foundSubcscription.addCompany(foundCompany, {
    through: {
      status: "active",
      paidStatus: "paid",
      subscriptionType: "Monthly",
      subscriptionPlanEndDate: moment().add(1, "months"),
      paidDate: moment().add(1, "months"),
    },
  });

  console.log("inserted data ", insertedData);
  res.json({ data: insertedData });
};
```

Now I want to fetch the records from db as which company has bought which subscription plan!
i.e. company name, subscription plan and its active and paid status and plan's expiry date.

I tried below code:

```
const billingList = async (req, res) => {
  const billingData = await CompanySubscription.findAll({
    include: [{ model: companies }],
  });

  console.log("billing data ", billingData);
};
```

Above code is throwing error "companies is not associated to CompanySubscription!".

Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to import models to each other's modules directly. Define model registration functions in each model module and use them all to register models in one place/module and for associations you can define `associate` function inside each registration function and call them after **ALL** your models are already registered. That way you won't have cyclic dependencies and all associations will be correct.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to get an idea how to do it.