# Using sequelize-auto generates init-models.js. Is my app utilizing this for associations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I'm working on an express rest api using sequelize.  I successfully generated my models using `sequelize-auto` (which created init-models.js) and haven't thought about it since.  My tables have associations and they show up in the init-models.js file but I can't seem to use query associating to utilize the associations.

Here's the init-models.js that sequelize-auto generated:

```js
function initModels(sequelize) {
  ...

  product.belongsTo(manufacturer, { as: "manufacturer", foreignKey: "manufacturer_id" });
  manufacturer.hasMany(product, { as: "products", foreignKey: "manufacturer_id"});

  return { product, manufacturer }
}

module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels
```

So my question is.. is this module getting loaded when my server starts and initializes everything?  If not, could I just move my associations directly to the model init function as suggested in the documentation (I think I'd rather do this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a better idea how to register and initialize models and their associations if you look at [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618).
As for shown generated code I suppose it would be better to call `initModels` inside the entry-point or a special DB module right after you have a Sequelize instance initialized to pass it to the function. And if you import this generated module then by default you will only have access to `initModels` to be able to call it wherever you wish to initialize models and to get them returned.

Comment: Great thank you!  I ended up creating my associations for each model inside the model.