# sequelize join up the tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, join, sequelize.js

Working on an already setup db and also new to sequelize. I have like four tables

1. customer
2. library
3. books
4. excerpt

`excerpt` has redundant `book_id` from `books`. `books` has redundant library_id from `library`, and `library` has redundant `customer_id` from `customer`.
They were not declared foreign in db but its kinda acting the foreign key type and I make the association when I hit the orm functions.

**My question:**
I have a `customer_id` and `book_id`, and I have to fetch `excerpt` records based on `book_id` but have to go top the db to match the `customer_id` as well. (for multi tenancy)
the flow is: *excerpt> book_id - books > library_id - library > customer_id - customer*

I have written this code but its not working

```
async read_book_id(customer_id, book_id) {
    const excerpts = await this.model.findAll({  // this.model being the excerpt model
      where: { book_id: book_id},
      include: [
        {
          model: this.db.Books,
          association:
             this.model.belongsTo(this.db.Books, {
                  foreignKey: 'book_id',
                }),
          where: { book_id: book_id},
          include: [
            {
              model: this.db.Library,
              association: this.model.belongsTo(this.db.Library, {
                foreignKey: 'library_id',
              }),
              where: { customer_id: customer_id },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
```

Basically this is something extended from this another code i wrote which is working for me. If I have to check only one level above thats working fine for me e.g

// reading books based on `library_id`

```
 async read(customer_id, library_id) {
    const books= await this.model.findAll({
      where: {
        library_id: library_id,
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: this.db.Library,
          association: this.model.belongsTo(this.db.Library, {
            foreignKey: 'library_id',
          }),
          where: { customer_id: customer_id },
        },
      ],
    });
  }
```

This works fine for me.

Can you please tell how to run the first code block?

Comment: First of all there is no need to register associations every time you execute a query. Just register them one time at the startup. You can get the idea how to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618

Comment: Second, you don't need `where: { book_id: book_id}` in the include with `Books` model

Comment: would the association reflect on the production db? Do I need migrations of any sort?

Comment: If you already have all needed foreign keys in DB and you don't use `sync` then associations are used by Sequelize only for joining tables correctly to get associated model's records

Comment: I dont have the foreign keys as I mentioned the db was already setup.

Comment: Then there is no harm in adding associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already registered all associations just like I suggested in the comments above you need to indicate the correct models in `include` options along with correct conditions:

````js
const excerpts = await this.model.findAll({  // this.model being the excerpt model
      where: { book_id: book_id},
      include: [
        {
          model: this.db.Books,
          include: [
            {
              model: this.db.Library,
              where: { customer_id: customer_id },
              required: true
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });```
````

Comment: This the second code block of mine. it was already working. I was asking about the first one.

Comment: The one where I have to look up to two more models

Comment: Yes, my bad, I corrected my answer

Comment: Considering the last comment you made to my question, I guess its ok to keep the association right? 
I removed the  `where: { book_id: book_id}` in the include with `Books` model

but still getting this error.
`column excerpt.library_id does not exist`

. Arent the `include` statements nested?

Comment: You also make mistake in `association: this.model.belongsTo(this.db.Library, {
            foreignKey: 'library_id',
          }),` because you needed to indicate `this.db.Books.belongsTo(this.db.Library`