# Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object. in Sequelize Postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models `create_project` and `create_stages`, to run the queries I have called the `model.associate` in each model

`create_project` model

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { getConnection } = require("../helper/databaseConnection");

const createProjectModel = {
  id: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  project_name: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(),
    allowNull: true,
  },
  project_code: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(200),
    allowNull: true,
  },
  isActive: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
    defaultValue: 1,
  },
};

let project = null;
const initProjectModel = async () => {
  try {
    if (project) return project;
    const sequelize = await getConnection();
    project = sequelize.define("create_project", createProjectModel, {
      freezeTableName: true,
    });

    project.associate = (models) => {
      project.hasMany(models.stages, { foreignKey: "project_id" });
    };

    await project.sync({ alter: true });
    return project;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
};

module.exports = { initProjectModel };
```

`create_stage` model

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { getConnection } = require("../helper/databaseConnection");

const createStagesModel = {
  id: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  stages_name: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  stages_code: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(200),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  isActive: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
    defaultValue: 1,
  },
};

let stages = null;
const initStagesModel = async () => {
  try {
    if (stages) return stages;
    const sequelize = await getConnection();
    stages = sequelize.define("create_stages", createStagesModel, {
      freezeTableName: true,
    });

    stages.associate = (models) => {
      stages.belongsTo(models.project, { foreignKey: "project_id" });
    };
    await stages.sync({ alter: true });
    return stages;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
};

module.exports = { initStagesModel };
```

code I have done to fetch the stages

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const { initStagesModel } = require("../models/stageModel");
const { initProjectModel } = require("../models/projectModel");

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const stageData = await initStagesModel();
    const projectData = await initProjectModel();
    const id = req.params.id;


    data = await projectData.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          models: stageData,
        },
      ],
      where: { id: id },
    });

    return res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err.stack);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

the problem is - it says *Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.*

stack

```
Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
at create_project._conformInclude (D:\one to many example\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:323:11)
at D:\one to many example\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:270:61
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at create_project._conformIncludes (D:\one to many example\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:270:39)
    at create_project._baseMerge (D:\one to many example\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:622:10)
    at create_project._defaultsOptions (D:\one to many example\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:656:17)
    at create_project._injectScope (D:\one to many example\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2001:10)
    at create_project.findAll (D:\one to many example\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1105:10)
    at D:\one to many example\controllers\listStages.js:23:30
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: In that Sequelize query, you have joined two tables, using the property include. that can contain an array of models. In that include property, each object should be like this {model: <model name>}, in your case you defined the property model in the plural, change it to singular, and check it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to initialize your models and associations properly.

1. You sync each model without completing the initialization of other models.
2. You didn't call `associate` method of registered models and Sequelize knows nothing about associations between models and thus can't utilize `include`  option in queries
3. Because you call `sync` without having all associations registered you won't have any foreign keys in DB that should correspond the associations.

To get the better idea how to register models and associations please look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)

P.S. Please check what `init<ModelName>` methods really return. It should be initialized Sequelize model object with methods such as `create`, `update`, `findAll` and so on.