# perfis.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm having a problem while using Sequelize in a MVC project. Every time I try to use the hasOne or hasMany it brings me the same error.
Some people had suggested to put every Models in a single file or creating a associations.js just to handle the associations. It works, but I personally don't think that's the best approach and I want to figure out a better alternative.

P.S: Using Postgre and Sequelize 6.28

Here is my code:

Models:
Perfil.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../../db/conn')

// MODELS
const User = require('./Usuario')

const Perfil = db.define('perfis', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    nome: DataTypes.STRING(90),
    descricao: DataTypes.TEXT('long')
}, { schema: "acesso", underscored: true })

Perfil.hasMany(User)

module.exports = Perfil
```

Usuarios.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../../db/conn')

// MODELS
const Perfil = require('./Perfil')

const Usuario = db.define('usuarios', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    nome: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false
    },
    nome_exibicao: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    sexo: DataTypes.STRING(45),
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 1
    }
}, { schema: "acesso", underscored: true });

Usuario.belongsTo(Perfil)

module.exports = Usuario
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to import models in each other's modules - these are circular dependencies. Please transform model registration code into functions in model modules and call them in one DB module registering associations only after all models will be registered.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to get the idea how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

For future's sake, to them who might land here...

Sequelize expects model names to be singular when 'associating'!! (Found out the hard way).

Therefore the filenames inside the models folder are expected to be singular too.

This piece of code from `models/index.js` picks model names from the models folder filenames, and applies them to associations

```
// get the Models
fs.readdirSync('./src/db/models')
    .filter(file => {
        return (
            file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
            file !== 'index.js' &&
            file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
            file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
        );
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = require(`./${file}`)(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

// get the Associations
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});
```

- The answer to the problem lies in using the filename `Usuarios.js`.

Note: when performing migrations use the actual table names, which may or may not be pluralized.

*Happy coding...*