# Sequelize Error: belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to associate models in Sequelize NodeJS and running into a problem, here are the two models that I have defined.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
'use strict';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import db from '../db';
import Review from './Review';

const Product = db.define(
  'Product',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    price: {
      type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    countInStock: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    numReviews: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    image: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    category: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    rating: {
      type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

Product.hasMany(Review, {
  foreignKey: 'productId',
  as: 'reviews'
});

export default Product;
```

And

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import db from '../db';
import User from './User';
import Product from './Product';

const Review = db.define(
  'Review',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    rating: {
      type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    comment: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    productId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Product,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
  }
);

Review.belongsTo(Product, {
  foreignKey: 'productId',
  as: 'product'
});

Review.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  as: 'user'
});



export default Review;
```

I get an error with belongsTo called with not thats not a subclass of Sequelize Model

I think all the foreignKeys are correct, what other errors am I missing?

It throws the error when I add the association in the Product Model

Comment: did you find the solution? Can you please post the solution

Comment: also would like to know if you found the solution

Comment: Ref this answer.. worked for me. [associating with Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652967/17849917)