# Sequelize Error: You have used the alias values in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases

Tags: sequelize.js, associations, alias, has-many, findall

**This is my code:**

```
public getSpecs = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const MasterSpecCategory = models[res.locals.project].master_spec_category;
      const MasterSpec = models[res.locals.project].master_spec;

      MasterSpecCategory.hasMany(MasterSpec, { as: 'values', foreignKey: 'spec_category_id' });  

      const get_specs = await MasterSpecCategory.findAll({ 
        include: {
          model: MasterSpec,
          as: 'values'
        },
      });

      return SuccessResponse(res, req.t('COMMON.OK'), get_specs);

    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
```

### **When I run this in "Postman", at first time it gives the correct output:**

[image]

### **But when I hit it again then it shows: "You have used the alias values in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases."**

[image]

The error in postman:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "success": false,
    "data": 500,
    "message": "You have used the alias values in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases."
}
```

### **Here are my models:**

1. *master_spec_category.ts*

```
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define(
      'master_spec_category', 
      {
          id: {
              autoIncrement: true,
              type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
              allowNull: false,
              primaryKey: true,
          },
          name: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
              allowNull: true
          },
          key: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
              allowNull: true
          },
          description: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: true
          },
          icon: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
              allowNull: true
          },
          type: {
              type: DataTypes.ENUM('int', 'option'),
              allowNull: true
          },
          status: {
              type: DataTypes.ENUM('hide','disable', 'enable' ),
              allowNull: true
          },
    
      }, 
      {
          tableName: 'master_spec_category',
          timestamps: false,
          indexes: [
              {
                name: "PRIMARY",
                unique: true,
                using: "BTREE",
                fields: [
                  { name: "id" },
                ]
              },
          ]
      }
  );
}
```

2. *master_spec.ts*

```
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    'master_spec', 
    {
          id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
          },
          spec_category_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
              model: 'master_spec_category',
              key: 'id',
            },
          },
          disp_order: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true
          },
          name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: true
          },
          description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
          },
          icon: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: true
          },
          status: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM('hide','disable', 'enable' ),
            allowNull: true
          },
    
      }, 
      {
          tableName: 'master_spec',
          timestamps: false,
          indexes: [
                {
                  name: "PRIMARY",
                  unique: true,
                  using: "BTREE",
                  fields: [
                    { name: "id" },
                  ]
                },
                {
                  name: 'fk_master_spec_master_spec_category',
                  using: 'BTREE',
                  fields: [
                    { name: 'id' }
                  ],
                },
            ]
        }
    );
};
```

**I think I had done all the things right, but still it giving that error on second hit in postman.**

Is there anyway to solve this??!!

Comment: Please dont post text information  as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't register associations every time you are about to execute Sequelize queries against models (`hasMany` in this case). Just register them once at the app startup.
Look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to get an idea how it might look like.