# I have an issue concerning the sequelize, TypeError: Market.hasMany is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

updated models.js, that's the models.js file I created with a reference for all my models, I have all my the models as individual file grouped in a models folder, so I made the reference and made the associations on the same file but now I get this error Failed to sync models with the database: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

```
const sequelize = require('./config/database');
const AdminModel = require('./models/adminModel');
const MarketModel = require('./models/marketModel');
const CartModel = require('./models/Cart');
const CartItemModel = require('./models/CartItem');
const ClientModel = require('./models/clientModel');
const PendingCartsListModel = require('./models/pendingCartsListModel');
const ProductModel = require('./models/productModel');
const SellerModel = require('./models/sellerModel');
const BoutiqueVirtuelleModel = 
require('./models/boutiqueVirtuelleModel');

const Admin = AdminModel;
const Market = MarketModel;
const BoutiqueVirtuelle = BoutiqueVirtuelleModel;
const Cart = CartModel;
const CartItem = CartItemModel;
const PendingCartsList = PendingCartsListModel;
const Product = ProductModel;
const Seller = SellerModel;
const Client = ClientModel;

// Define associations
Market.belongsToMany(Admin, { through: 'MarketAdmin', foreignKey: 
'marketId' });
Admin.belongsTo(Market, { foreignKey: 'marketId' });
Seller.hasOne(BoutiqueVirtuelle, { foreignKey: 'marketId' });
Seller.belongsTo(Market, { foreignKey: 'marketId' });
Client.hasOne(Cart, { foreignKey: 'clientId' });
BoutiqueVirtuelle.belongsTo(Market, { foreignKey: 'marketId' });
BoutiqueVirtuelle.belongsTo(Seller, { foreignKey: 'sellerId' });  
Product.belongsTo(BoutiqueVirtuelle, { foreignKey: 'boutiqueVirtuelleId' 
});
Product.belongsToMany(Cart, { through: CartItem, foreignKey: 'productId' 
});
Cart.belongsTo(Client, { foreignKey: 'clientId' });
Cart.belongsToMany(Product, { through: CartItem, foreignKey: 'cartId' 
});
Market.belongsToMany(Seller, { through: 'MarketSeller', foreignKey: 
'marketId' });
PendingCartsList.belongsToMany(Cart, { through: 
'PendingCartListCart', 
  foreignKey: 'listId', as: 'carts' });



// Export the models
module.exports = {
  Admin,
  Market,
  BoutiqueVirtuelle,
  Cart,
  CartItem,
  Client,
  Product,
  PendingCartsList,
  Seller
};
```

also here is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sequelize = require('./config/database');
const models = require('./models');
const clientRoutes = require('./routes/clientRoutes');
const sellerRoutes = require('./routes/sellerRoutes');
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/adminRoutes');
const productRoutes = require('./routes/productRoutes');
const cartRoutes = require('./routes/cartRoutes');
const marketRoutes = require('./routes/marketRoutes');
const boutiqueVirtuelleRoutes = 
require('./routes/boutiqueVirtuelleRoutes');


// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Parse incoming request bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Sync the models with the database
sequelize.sync( {alter: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Models synchronized with the database');
    // Start your server or perform other operations
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to sync models with the database:', error);
  });

// Define API routes
app.use('/api/client', clientRoutes);
app.use('/api/seller', sellerRoutes);
app.use('/api/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use('/api/products', productRoutes);
app.use('/api/cart', cartRoutes);
app.use('/api/market', marketRoutes);
app.use('/api/boutiqueVirtuelle', boutiqueVirtuelleRoutes);

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Can you share `marketModel` file?

Comment: Try to turn model modules into model constructor functions and register them all and their associations in one place, see my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618

Comment: I did what @Anatoly talked about but now I get 
Failed to sync models with the database: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

Comment: Please update the post with the latest code with models, registration and so on