# Sequelize.js is not associated to

Tags: sequelize.js

I have some issue with "mst_rack is not associated to mst_part!"

**RacksModel** u can see my code below

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import db from "../config/Database.js";
import Parts from "./PartModel.js";

const {DataTypes} = Sequelize;
const Racks = db.define('mst_rack',{
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: 'ID'
    },
    rack_no:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING(10)
    }, 
},{
  freezeTableName:true 
});

Racks.associate = function(models) {
    Parts.belongsTo(models.mst_rack, {foreignKey: 'id'});
}

export default Racks;
```

**PartModel**  u can see my code below

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import db from "../config/Database.js";
import Racks from "./RackModel.js";

const {DataTypes} = Sequelize;

const Parts = db.define('mst_part',{
    part_no:{
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(10)
    },
    part_name:{
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100)
    },
    part_uniq:{
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100)
    },
    mst_rackId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
        model: 'mst_rack',
        key: 'ID'
    },
        field: 'id_rack'
    }
},{
      freezeTableName:true
});

Parts.associate = function(models) {
    Racks.hasOne(models.mst_rack, {foreignKey: 'id',sourceKey: 'mst_rackId'});

}

export default Parts;
```

**Part Controller**  u can see my code below

```
import Parts from "../models/PartModel.js";
import Racks from "../models/RackModel.js"

export const getParts = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const parts = await Parts.findAll({
            attributes:['id','part_no', 'part_name', 'part_uniq', 'id_rack'],
            include: [
                {model: Racks},
                {model: Racks, as: 'PartRack'},
            ]
    })
        res.json(parts);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
 }
```

and i get some error below

**Error Message**

at mst_part._getIncludedAssociation (D:!Develop\be-stock-opname\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:565:13)
at mst_part._validateIncludedElement (D:!Develop\be-stock-opname\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:502:53)
at D:!Develop\be-stock-opname\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:421:37
at Array.map ()
at mst_part._validateIncludedElements (D:!Develop\be-stock-opname\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:417:39)
at mst_part.findAll (D:!Develop\be-stock-opname\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1124:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async getParts (file:///D:/!Develop/be-stock-opname/controllers/Part.js:6:23)

And the simple question - what's wrong ? :)
I want to get Part with specific Rack

Answer (score 0):

Remove models cross-references in their modules. Exchange association definitions the way that the main model should be the model from the current module (so you don't need to import the other model):
**RacksModel**

```js
Racks.associate = function(models) {
    Racks.hasOne(models.mst_part, {foreignKey: 'id',sourceKey: 'mst_rackId'});
}
```

**PartModel**

```js
Parts.associate = function(models) {
   Parts.belongsTo(models.mst_rack, {foreignKey: 'id'});
}
```

Also I didn't see the association definition with the alias `PartRack` indicated in the query and I didn't found the code that calls `associate` methods of all models.

All in all I recommend to use the approach I showed in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to register and use models properly.

Comment: mst_rack is not associated to mst_part!

Part Controller
 `   const parts = await Parts.findAll({
                attributes:['id','part_no', 'part_name', 'part_uniq', 'id_rack'],
                include: [
                    {model: Racks}
                ]  
            })`

RackModel
`Racks.associate = function(models) {
    Racks.hasOne(models.mst_part, {foreignKey: 'id',sourceKey: 'mst_rackId'});
}`

Part Model
`Parts.associate = function(models) {
    Parts.belongsTo(models.mst_rack, {foreignKey: 'id'});
 }`

Comment: Check if you call `associate` method for all models after you registered them all. Check if associations prop in the `Parts` model is not empty right before calling `findAll`

Comment: And please update the post with the actual code and corrected association defintions