# Associations not working with express + sequelize

Tags: express, sequelize.js, associations

My assoications are not working with sequelize + express. My models are working, however the associations do not work. I have tried chaning everything, to no success

```
index.js 
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

require("dotenv").config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "postgres",
    operatorAliases: false,
    pool: { max: 5, min: 0, acquire: 30000, idle: 10000 },
  }
);

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.words = require("./wordModel.js")(sequelize, DataTypes);
db.lessons = require("./lessonModel.js")(sequelize, DataTypes);

module.exports = db;
```

lessonModel

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Lesson = sequelize.define("Lesson", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    number: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  });

  Lesson.associate = function (models) {
    Lesson.hasMany(models.Word, {
      as: "Words",
      foreignKey: "lessonId",
    });
  };

  return Lesson;
};
```

wordModel

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Word = sequelize.define("Word", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    english: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    portuguese: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    lastStudied: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    toBeStudiedDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    timesSeen: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    timesWrong: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    percentage: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    lastFiveArray: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    },
    lastFivePercentage: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    image: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    sound: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    lessonId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
    },
  });

  Word.associate = function (models) {
    Word.belongsTo(models.Lesson, { as: "Lesson", foreignKey: "lessonId" });
  };

  return Word;
};
```

app.js

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
require("dotenv").config();
const db = require("./models");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const wordsRouter = require("./routes/words");
const lessonsRouter = require("./routes/lessons");

var app = express();

db.sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(async () => {
    const lesson = await db.lessons.create({ name: "Example Lesson" });
    await lesson.save();

    const word = await db.words.create({
      english: "Hello",
      lessonId: lesson.id,
    });
    await word.save();

    console.log(word.Lesson);

    console.log("Synced db.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Failed to sync db: " + err.message);
  });

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/words", wordsRouter);
app.use("/lessons", lessonsRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

I get a variety of errors. I recently started trying to console.log(word.Lesson) or a variety of word.getLesson(). Depending on how I am trying to test the assoication, I get the following errors:

Failed to sync db: Word is not associated to Lesson!

When I try and console.log I get undefined.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the `associate` method of all registered models in order to register all associations, please do it, for instance, in `index.js`.
To get the idea how to do it properly you can look at my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)