# Can anyone help me with sequelize associations and tell me where i am going wrong

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

[This is the schema I have to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kmYX.png)

I have created the user and community model

```
const Seqeulize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const Community = require('./Community');

const User = db.define('User', {
  id: {
    type: Seqeulize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: Seqeulize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull: {
        msg: 'A name is required',
      },
      len: {
        args: [2, 64],
        msg: 'Your name must be atleast 2 character long',
      },
    },
  },
  email: {
    type: Seqeulize.STRING(128),
    allowNull: false,
    unique: {
      msg: 'email already taken',
    },
    validate: {
      isEmail: true,
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: Seqeulize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull: {
        msg: 'A password is required',
      },
      len: {
        args: [6, 64],
        msg: 'Your password must be atleast 6 character long',
      },
    },
  },
});

User.beforeCreate(async (user, options) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
  user.password = hashedPassword;
});

User.prototype.validatePassword = (candidatePassword, dbPassword) => {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, dbPassword);
};

User.hasMany(Community);
module.exports = User;
```

This is my User model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db');

const Community = db.define('Community', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(128),
    allowNull: false,
    unique: {
      msg: 'Name already taken',
    },
  },
  slug: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false,
    unique: {
      msg: 'slug already created',
    },
  },
  owner: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    references: {
      model: 'Users',
      key: 'id',
    },
  },
});

Community.associate = (models) => {
  Community.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: 'owner',
    as: 'Owner',
  });
};

module.exports = Community;
```

This is my Community Model

```
const communities = await Community.findAll(
    paginate(
      {
        where: {
          owner: req.user.id,
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            as: 'Owner',
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
          },
        ],
      },
      { page, pageLimit: limit }
    )
  );
```

Running this function gives me this error:   "message": "User is not associated to Community!",

While logging the query it is only running

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "email", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = '7115021805874438051';
```

Can someone help me resolve this

I have tried created 2-3 ways of creating associations like only using User.hasMany and Community.belongsTo without the use of Model.associate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You used two different approaches:

1. Import models in each other's modules to be able to associate them on the root level of the module
2. Define associations in a special model's function - `associate`

I'd recommend to use only one of them (the best one is the second one) and firstly register all models and only after that call `associate` for all models.

You can get the idea how to do it from my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)

Comment: Firstly, tried using the same method for both the associations --> calling`associate` on the models did not work. Secondly, I have not defined all my models at one place, they are all defined in their respective files in the models forlder. Also i have not used sequelize-cli and `sequelize init` to set up my database and other configurations. Still thanks for responding on my question.

Comment: I meant you shouldn't import models into each other model modules. Just use `associate` after all models will be registered. You can easily check associations of a certain model right before calling its method by checking `associations` prop.