# initUserModel is not a function TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

addressModel.js

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { getConnection } = require("../db");
const { initUserModel } = require("./userModel");
const { RESPONSE } = require("../response");
const { send } = require("../responseHelper");


const addressModel = {
  address_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  address: {
    type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
  },

};

const initAddressModel = async (res) => {
  try {
    const sequelize = await getConnection();
    const user = await initUserModel();
    const address = sequelize.define("address", addressModel, {
      freezeTableName: true,
    });

   address.belongsTo(user, {
      as: "addressInfo",
      onDelete: "cascade",
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false,
        name: "user_id",
      },
      targetKey: "user_id",
    });

    await address.sync({ alter: true });
    return address;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return send(res, RESPONSE.ERROR, err.message);

  }
};

module.exports = { initAddressModel };
```

userMOdel.js

```
//const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const { getConnection } = require("../db");
const { RESPONSE } = require("../response");
const { send } = require("../responseHelper");
const { initAddressModel } = require("./addressModel");

const userSchema = {
  user_id: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false, // Make it not nullable
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },

}

const initUserModel = async (res) => {
  try {
   const address = await initAddressModel();
    const sequelize = await getConnection();
    const user = sequelize.define("user", userSchema, {
      freezeTableName: true,
    });


    user.hasMany(address,{foreignKey:"user_id"})

    await user.sync({ alter: true });
    return user;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
    return send(res,RESPONSE.ERROR,err.stack)
  }
};

module.exports = {initUserModel };
```

here i am trying to BelogsTo and hasMany inside the program to access the user_id of userModel from addressModel

> if i use only only BelongsTo then addressModel can access the user_id from the userModel
> But if i use hasMany inside userModel then i will not read the properties of userModel from addressModel

> it shows the error initUserModel is not function

> i have already seen thta all import and exports are done perfectly

Comment: It's not good to cross-reference models. Look at the question and my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618 to get an idea how to register models and their associations