# User.hasMany is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have models User and Order for my database. But when i starting my script throwing exception:  User.hasMany is not a function.

```
// ./models/user.js

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
    return User;
};
```

```
// ./models/order.js

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { User } = require('./user')

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: User,
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    });
    return Order;
};
```

```
// index.js

const User = require('./models/user');
const Order = require('./models/order');

User.hasMany(Order, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
Order.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Database & tables created')
    });
```

I tried adding communication inside models:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const Order = require("./order");
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
    User.hasMany(Order, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
    return User;
};
```

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { User } = require('./user')

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: User,
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    });
    Order.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
    return Order;
};
```

but that's another problem

> (node:9264) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'User' of module exports inside circular dependency
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove all cross-references from model modules:

`order.js`

```js
//const { User } = require('./user')

userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'User',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
```

Second, you need to register models calling their constructor function and passing `sequelize` instance there because all models are exported as a constructor function and not as a ready-to-use model instance:

`index.js`

```js
const User = require('./models/user')(sequelize);
const Order = require('./models/order')(sequelize);

User.hasMany(Order, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
Order.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Database & tables created')
    });
```

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) to get an idea how to register models properly along with their associations