# EagerLoadingError in Sequelize (association between models)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an error that I don't understand, I'm trying to make it as simple as possible. A simple findAll with an include. (like in the doc : https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/ )

```
async function getAllTasks() {
  try {
    const tasks = await Task.findAll({
      include: User,
    });
    return tasks;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

In my associations.js :

```
function applyExtraSetup(sequelize) {
const User = require("./User");
const Task= require("./Task");

 Task.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId" });
 User.hasMany(Task, { foreignKey: "userId" });

}
module.exports = { applyExtraSetup };
```

And in my Task model, I have an attribute userId :

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../../config/database"); 
const User = require("./User");

const Task = sequelize.define(
  "Task",
  {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: "id",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "Tasks",
  }
);

module.exports = Task;
```

And my init.js where I call the association file :

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("./config/database");
const { applyExtraSetup } = require("./app/models/associations");

const User = require("./app/models/User");
const Task = require("./app/models/Task");

// We execute any extra setup after the models are defined, such as adding associations.
applyExtraSetup(sequelize);

sequelize.sync({ alter: true }).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

And my error : `EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: User is not associated to Task!`

Any ideas ? I tried many things but nothing works ...
Thanks !

**Solution with help of Anatoly**
Add a static method Associate in my model:

```
class Task extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    Task.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "userId" });
  }
}

Task.init(
  {
    // Model attributes are defined here
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: "Tasks",
  }
);

module.exports = Task;
```

And add this in my init.js :

```
const models = require("./app/models");
Object.values(models).forEach((model) => {
  console.log(model.associate);
  if (model.associate) {
    model.associate(models);
  }
});
```

It's not in the doc, and I didn't understand everything, but it works. We must be able to improve/optimize. Thanks to Anatoly !

Comment: Show the full model modules and a piece of code where you register them and call associations

Comment: Hello @Anatoly, i edited my post with init.js and the full model of Task

Comment: I don't see what `applyExtraSetup` does

Comment: Hello @Anatoly, sorry I didn't specify. applyExtraSetup is the function called in my association file. (i edited my post)

Comment: Try to use all registered models from sequelize instance even in `applyExtraSetup`. Also look at my other answer here to get an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618

Comment: Thanks ! It works, but it's very weird. I edited my post