# Unable to import models and create associations in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, sequelize.js, associations

I am working in a Twitter-like backend system. There's a TweetService and a CommentService both in separate folders. Im using sequelize for the models and associations between models.The models which I want to associate are in different services and when I am trying to associate them Im getting the following error:

`Tweet.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`

The file structure for the models is : [image]  [image]

Thus when I am trying to associate using the following code :

```
static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(Tweet,{
        foreignKey:'tweetId',
        onDelete:'CASCADE'
      })
    }
```

Im getting the error.I've imported the models in different folders using :

```
const {Tweet}=require('../../../TweetService/src/models/index')
```

Comment: You should use `Tweet` from `models` parameters

Comment: @Anatoly Thats what I said ,since Tweet model  is in different service, its not there in the models parameters

Comment: If you use the same Sequelize instance and pass its `models` props in `associate` methods of models then there will be all registered models

Comment: @Anatoly how do I do so?

Comment: Try to get the idea from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618