How to establish a one-to-many relationship using sequelize in Nodejs?
I have a model called users.model.js
const postsModel = require("../Posts/posts.model");

const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: (user) => {
                user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10)
            }
        },
    },
);

User.hasMany(postsModel,{foreignKey:"createdBy",as:"posts"});

User.sync({ force: true }).then(()=>{
    console.log("Synced user model with DB")
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  });

module.exports = User;


And another model called posts.model.js
const usersModel = require("../Users/users.model");

const Post = sequelize.define(
    'Post',
    {
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
        },
        desc: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull:false,
        },
        createdBy: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            references:{
                model:"User",
                key:"id"
            },
            allowNull:false,
        },
    },
    { freezeTableName: true }
);

Post.belongsTo(usersModel);

Post.sync({ force: true }).then(()=>{
    console.log("Synced post model with DB")
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  });

module.exports = Post;

I am trying to populate all the posts that belongs to a user using below code:
const foundUser = await usersModel.findOne(
            {
                where:
                    { username: req.body.username },
                include: [{ model: sequelize.model("Post") }],
            });


But i am getting this error:
Error: Post.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
I tried following:

Post.belongsTo(sequelize.model("User")) - This is throwing Error: User has not been defined.
Post.belongsTo("User") - This is throwing Error: Post.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
I also tried using Post.associate but that method is not available in the version of sequelize i am using (6.37.3).

I want to populate all posts related to the user based on user.id.

Just try not to use models in each other modules and to register all associations after all models will be registered in Sequelize, see my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618
