Dynamically call sequelize models using tablename
I have to call sequelize models dynamically using the tablenames, also include their associations dynamically. Is there a way to do this? Is it possible?
I have got the models dynamically but not their associations. I have to create a dynamic sequelize query generator with that.
My error is:
Error in query generation:  EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: table1 is not associated to table2!
at table2._getIncludedAssociation
(I have already defines the assocaition in the models)
Here is what I have tried:
async function buildDynamicReportQuery(data, sequelize) {

  const { tableNames, joinDetails, selectedColumns, whereConditions } = data;

  // Load models dynamically for the specified tables
  const models = {};
  for (const tableName of tableNames) {
    models[tableName] = await getModel(tableName);
    const mode = sequelize.models[tableName];

    if (mode) {
      console.log(`Model name for table '${tableName}' is: ${mode.name}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`No model found for table '${tableName}'`);
    }
  }

  // Build the SELECT clause
  const attributes = [];
  for (const [table, columns] of Object.entries(selectedColumns)) {
    console.log('TABLE', table)
    console.log('Columns', columns)
    columns.forEach(column => {
      attributes.push([sequelize.col(`${table}.${column}`), column]);
    });
  }

  // Build the JOIN clauses
  const include = joinDetails.map(join => ({
    model: models[join.targetTable],
    as: join.targetTable, // alias the table for easier access
    on: {
      [`${join.sourceTable}.${join.sourceColumn}`]: sequelize.col(`${join.targetTable}.${join.targetColumn}`)
    },
    required: join.joinType === 'INNER', // INNER JOIN if required, LEFT JOIN otherwise
    right: join.joinType === 'RIGHT',
  }));

  // Build the WHERE conditions
  const where = {};
  const conditionGroups = {};
  
  whereConditions.forEach(condition => {
    const { table, column, operator, value, followUp } = condition;

    if (!conditionGroups[table]) {
      conditionGroups[table] = [];
    }

    let sequelizeOp;
    switch (operator) {
      case '=':
        sequelizeOp = Op.eq;
        break;
      case '>':
        sequelizeOp = Op.gt;
        break;
      case '<':
        sequelizeOp = Op.lt;
        break;
      case 'LIKE':
        sequelizeOp = Op.like;
        break;
      case 'BETWEEN':
        sequelizeOp = Op.between;
        break;
      default:
        sequelizeOp = Op.eq; // Default to equality if unsupported
    }

    const conditionObject = {
      [column]: {
        [sequelizeOp]: value,
      },
    };

    conditionGroups[table].push(conditionObject);

    if (followUp === 'OR') {
      where[Op.or] = conditionGroups[table];
    } else if (followUp === 'AND' || !followUp) {
      where[Op.and] = conditionGroups[table];
    }
  });

  // Perform the query
  const result = await models[tableNames[0]].findAll({
    attributes:attributes,
    include:include,
    where:where,
    raw: true, // Returns plain objects
  });

  return result;
 
}

// Example function to dynamically generate the model if not registered
async function getModel(tableName) {
  return sequelize.define(tableName, {
    tableName,
    timestamps: false,
  });
}



Did you register models and their associations correctly? Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618 to get the idea
